# Does EVERY brand new PlayStation TV ship with 3.60 firmware or lower?

Tags: playstation-tv

I know, the reason I'm asking this seems pretty obvious, but please ignore it.

Let's say I'd like to know if every brand new (not used) PlayStation TV that is shipped by a reliable reseller (one that does not open the box) delivers with a firmware that is lower than version 3.60.

I am in Europe (Italy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this you won't find a new, unopened PS TV with firmware past 3.60.

From what I can tell, this is likely due to the fact that PS TVs were discontinued early this year, see [here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/playstation-tv-discontinued-in-the-us-europe/1100-6435193/):

> A representative for the company confirmed to GameSpot on Monday that shipments for the device stopped at the end of 2015 in the Americas and Europe.

Since the PS TV uses the same OS as the PS Vita, I looked for the firmware release history for Vita and according to [this site](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2016/08/08/ps-vita-update-3-61-today-improves-system-performance/), firmware version 3.61 for Playstation Vita was released August 2016, which was after the PS TV was discontinued.

Since PS TVs are no longer being shipped, any new PS TV you buy will have been shipped prior to version 3.61 or later.

Comment: YEAH!!! Henkak... uhmm... 3.60, I'm coming!

Comment: @alex2003super what

Comment: @alex2003super I don't understand what you mean. You can still update it, it just won't come with the latest firmware.

Comment: I need an older version because firmwares below 3.61 come along with Kernels that have a critical vulnerability. This vulnerability allows users to hack the PS VITA and install custom apps that Sony doesn't want. Apps like a File Manager, a Save decrypter, a PlayStation TV PSVITA games whitelist disabler. All cool apps, that Sony doesn't want but aren't necessarily illegal. The hack is named Henkaku, and it took years to develop. It only works with 3.60 or lower, that's why I'm asking. Because PS VITA can't be downgraded.

Comment: @alex2003super OH, you wanted it at a LOWER version. I totally misunderstood. I thought you wanted to avoid updating, hahaha.